# Get all the words between two specific words in python

Tags: python, regex, string, substring

I have some string like these:

```
The pizza is so hot
Today I bought an hot and tasty pizza
```

I need to extract all the words between **pizza** and the adjective **hot** in python. How can I do??

These are an example of the output.

```
is so 
and tasty
```

Please take in mind that the attribute (pizza for example) and the adjective (hot for example) could be a multi-token word.

That's what I tried:

```
  attribute = re.search(values[0], descrizione, re.IGNORECASE)
  value = re.search(names[0], descrizione, re.IGNORECASE)
    if (attribute):
        print (attribute.group())
        print (descrizione.find(attribute.group()))

    if (value):
        print (value.group())
        print (descrizione.find(value.group()))
```

Comment: Can pizza and hot appear multiple times in a line?  How should it handle that?

Comment: @BrendanAbel no. They can't :D

Comment: Do you need to find the words in multiple strings, or just the two?

Comment: Multiple strings not only 2... The adjective can be before the attribute or after the attribute

Comment: sounds like a good use for pyparsing

Answer (score 4):

A different approach, you can define your "from/to" patterns as you desire.

```
>>> import regex
>>> rgx = regex.compile(r'(?si)(?|{0}(.*?){1}|{1}(.*?){0})'.format('pizza', 'hot'))
>>> s1 = 'The pizza is so hot'
>>> s2 = 'Today I bought an hot and tasty pizza'
>>> for s in [s1, s2]:
...     m = rgx.findall(s)
...     for x in m:
...         print x.strip()

is so
and tasty
```

Comment: line 82, in <module>
    rgx = re.compile(r'(?si)(?|{0}(.*?){1}|{1}(.*?){0})'.format(attribute.group(), value.group()))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 242, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression

Comment: You need to use the regex module. Not re.

Comment: This will not work for Python 3.9 - I believe you should indeed use the *re* module.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good solution would be to make use of split, and the '|' character in regex.

```
strs = []
strs.append('The pizza is so hot')
strs.append('Today I bought a hot and tasty pizza')
item = 'pizza'
adj = 'hot'
rets = []

for str_ in strs:
    ret = re.split(item + '|' + adj, str_, re.IGNORECASE)
    rets.append(ret[1].strip())
```

This works because when we consider the two strings individually we get a list with three elements.

```
ret = re.split(item + '|' + adj, strs[0], re.IGNORECASE)
print ret
['the ', ' is so ', '']

ret = re.split(item + '|' + adj, strs[1], re.IGNORECASE)
print ret
['Today I bought a ', ' and tasty ', '']
```

Since we know that both words can only occur once in the string, we can reliably take ret[1] as the result, because the string should only be split twice: once when we find one of the words, and again when we find the other. The OR character let's us split the list without knowing the order of the words ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

```
x="""The pizza is so hot
Today I bought an hot and tasty pizza
wow pizza and another pizza"""
print [j for i,j in re.findall(r"(pizza|hot)\s*(.*?)\s*(?!\1)(?:hot|pizza)",x)]
```

Try this with `re.findall`.